# How to convert Dynamically Sized VirtualBox Hard Drive to a Fixed size?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I have been trying to convert the Dynamically sized hard drive to a fixed size to increase the VM box performance. I tried to follow the instruction on [Convert Dynamically Sized VirtualBox VDI Hard Drive to Fixed Size](http://maxrohde.com/2014/06/21/convert-dynamically-sized-virtualbox-vdi-hard-drive-to-fixed-size/)

But I keep running into an issue when trying to manually remove the old drive Here is the command that I am trying to use

> vboxmanage closemedium disk "3f883a9e-037a-4f67-8ed4-f82ea2c7a84b"
>   –delete

Which gives me this error

> c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage closemedium disk
>   "3f883a9e-037a-4f 67-8ed4-f82ea2c7a84b" VBoxManage.exe: error: Medium
>   'C:\Users\malhayek\VirtualBox VMs\settler_default_
>   1434987271004_24349_1438813340021_48330\box-disk1.vmdk' cannot be
>   closed because  it is still attached to 1 virtual machines
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE
>   (0x80bb000c), componen t MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee
>   IUnknown VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "Close()" at line 1551 of
>   file VBoxManageDisk.cpp

What can I do to correctly set the hard drive size to Fixed?

Comment: Is that disk currently part of a virtual machine? It seems like that's what is happening here, check all your VM's and if you find the one using that disk, shut it down and remove the disk from it then try the closemedium command again.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is about the fact that you cannot delete an harddrive if it's still attached to a VM, so you should remove it as reported in the article:

> Open the virtual box manager, go to settings for your machine and
>   remove the old (dynamically sized) drive from the SATA controller for
>   this machine.

Important: as the article itself says, be careful and make sure you have a backup.